# importing a valid package is causing a java compiler error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-8, java-7

I am getting a compiler error when compiling Order.java file even when it contains an import statement for the other packaged class. Im not entirely sure why this is happening but here is a directory tree with some files that I have:

- com/my/domain/Order.java
  Inside this file are the following package and imports:

  ```
  package domain;
  import utils.MyDate;
  ```
- com/my/utils/MyDate.java
  Inside this file are the following package and imports:

  ```
  package utils;
  ```

Compiler error I get when compiling Order.java :

```
 Order.java:2: error: package com.my.utils does not exist
 import com.my.utils.MyDate;
               ^
 Order.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
  public MyDate orderDate;
       ^
  symbol:   class MyDate
  location: class Order

 Order.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
  public Order(MyDate d, double amt, String c, String p, int q){
             ^
 symbol:   class MyDate
 location: class Order

 Order.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
  public Order (MyDate d, double amt, String c) {
              ^
 symbol:   class MyDate
 location: class Order
4 errors
```

I am still unsure how to solve this after trying form the comments. Here is some more detail.

Existing Statements in .bash_profile :

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
 export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/Users/3aCaGa/Desktop/Java-SE-8-Programs/SimplifiedDateClass/com/my
```

How I am trying to compile? I am going to the java file location in the directory and running command for example :

```
 java Order.java
```

For more detail on the files that and their exact contents see:
https://github.com/gosem01/Java-SE-8-Programs/tree/master/SimplifiedDateClass/com/my

Comment: What is your `classpath`?

Comment: based upon `com/my/utils/MyDate.java` maybe `import com.my.MyDate;`

Comment: Here is my class path: `export PATH=$PATH/Users/3aCaGa/Desktop/Java-SE-8-Programs/SimplifiedDateClass/com` also changing it to `import com.my.MyDate;` got rid of the error but now I have the cannot find symbol error when I compile Order.java: `Order.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
import com.my.MyDate;`

Comment: 1- that is not the **CLASS**PATH it is just the PATH; 2- it is missing the separator ':' between `$PATH` and `/Users/...` (assuming non-Windows)

Comment: and if that were the classpath, it is missing the `my` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package and import statements do not match your directory structure.

Your *Order.class* should have:

```
package com.my.domain;
import com.my.utils.MyDate;
```

and the *Utils.class*:

```
package com.my.utils;
```

Answer (score 1):

To compile  go to the directory where you can "see" the com folder and do:

***nix/MacOS**

```
javac -cp . com/my/domain/*.java com/my/utils/*.java
```

**Windows**

```
javac -cp . com\my\domain\*.java com\my\utils\*.java
```

Hope it helps

Comment: more like `javac -cp com/my/ com/my/domain/*.java com/my/utils/*.java` ... or `cd com/my` and `javac -cp . domain/*.java utils/*.java`

Comment: @P.J.Meisch it is not moved anywhere just specifying the classpath using cp argument you can verify it using man javac

Comment: you're right; I mistook the `cp` as a shell command; sorry, just removed my previous coment